# Angular Dart - execute a function right after ng-repeat has finished

Tags: dart, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-dart

Searching stackoverflow for this question always give me the solution for Angular.js.

How would you do this in Anuglar dart?

That is I want to have a function run after an ng-repeat directive in angular dart has finished rendering its elements.

**EDIT:**

It turns out that knowing when ng-repeat has finished enumerating doesn't means the appropriate dom element has being attached to the document.

> I guess my intended question was how to determine when all
>   elements enumerated by ng-repeat is attached to the dom tree and can be
>   queried by selector

**EDIT2**

```
<div ng-repeat='fruit in fruits'>
 <li class="fruit">{{fruit}}</li>
</div>
querySelectorAll('.fruit'); // should return all <li> element created by ng-repeat
                            // the trick is knowing when and where to call querySelectorAll
```

Thanks

Comment: Would have helped if you had linked that Angular.js question. What do you actually mean by `when ng-repeat` has finished. After the first generation of the items? What about updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried `{{foo($last)}}` and it didn't work for me either.

This example uses `MutationObserver` to get notified about added elements.
I tried it and it worked.

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-cloak>
    <ul somefruits>
     <li ng-repeat='fruit in ctrl.fruits track by $index'
     class="fruit" ng-class="{'ng-last': $last}">{{fruit}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

```dart
library angular_default_header.main;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgController(selector: '[somefruits]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class Fruits {
  Fruits(){
    print('fruits created');
  }

  List fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Kiwi'];
}


class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    type(Fruits);
  }
}

void mutationCallback(List<MutationRecord> mutations, MutationObserver observer) {
  mutations.forEach((mr) {
    mr.addedNodes.forEach((Node n) {
      if(n is Element) {
        if(n.classes.contains('ng-last')) {
          print('last added');
          observer.disconnect();
          n.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

main() {
  print('main');
  var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  new MutationObserver(mutationCallback).observe(ul, childList: true);
  ngBootstrap(module: new MyAppModule());
}
```

Comment: {{foo($last)}}
void foo(bool isLast) {} worked for me

Comment: Actually, I just found out that knowing when ng-repeat has finished enumerating is not enough, because it doesn't necessary mean that the appropriate dom element has being attached to the document. See my edit

Comment: Can you post a code example to reproduce what you are trying to do. Another attempt would be to use mutation observers. You can add `$last` to the markup and setup up a mutation observer that checks if an element with class `ng-last` (not sure if this is the actual class value) was added.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example that I have tried successfully.

Answer (score 1):

See [angular.NgRepeatDirective](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular.NgRepeatDirective)

```
`$last` [bool]   true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.
```

However unless your list is fairly large, should not most of the elements be drawn at roughly the same time? Perhaps you could [watch](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core/Scope.html#%24watch) the collection for changes.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this GitHub issue (https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/843) for more information.

It smells like a bug to me, but I'm not sure.

As a workaround you could schedule a future outside of angular. There's more info about this in the above mentioned issue.